# Can't give default value to database text field in laravel app (mysql)

Tags: php, laravel

in my laravel app I have a Post "body" field of text type, I'm trying to give the field a default value like "This sis the default text for a blog post, feel free to change it" but mysql is throwing an error.

```
$table->text('body')->default('This is the default text for a blog post, feel free to change it.');
```

This isn't working...

According to docs BLOB/TEXT fields CAN'T have default values, this is pretty weird tbh.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html

I guess I could change the field type from text to string but afaik string won't have as many characters as string type and I knpw for certain that my Blog posts will be loooong. How could I approach this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need a default? Just leave it `NULL`

Comment: why wouldn't I give it one? I need it to have one.

Comment: The original request to add a default to the TEXT field is now possible by using an expression for the default - [Laravel Migrations - Default Expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#default-expressions) E.g. `$table->text('my_text_field)->default(new Expression('("My default text")'));`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Accessors & Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)
Here is an example for setting default value for body
What it does is that every time your model is going to save in database it checks if value is null then it sets your default value
Just put below code into your model.

```php
public function setBodyAttribute($value = null)
    {
        if (null === $value) {
            $this->attributes['body'] = 'default value';
        }

        $this->attributes['body'] = $value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set it to nullable `$table->text('body')->nullable(true);`
And in your view just give it a default text if it is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you can't give text default value. 
Solutions:

- Convert it to `varchar` ( You can have max 255 characters in one row)
- Give default value with code ( during creating, after creating, default placeholder text ... )